# Read checkbox values from excel using python without using win32 library

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

I Need to read check boxes and have accomplished using below

```
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
 wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(r'\Test.xlsx')
 ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
 cb_dict = {}
for cb in ws.CheckBoxes():
  cb_dict[cb.Name] = cb.Value
  print(cb_dict)
excel.Application.quit()
```

The below works fine when called from windows but when this python scripts is called in other OS systems win32 library doesnt seem to be compatible

if anyone have a different approach please share

Comment: I think that's expected as `win32` is made for windows.

Answer (score 0):

Unzip the `name.xlxs` table file to the folder. You'll find a file `name/xl/drawings/vmlDrawing1.vml`. There is the information including `Anchor`, `Checked`. The `value` of the checkbox in the front of the `shape`.

We can parse the `vmlDrawing1.vml` just like parse other XML file. I used `xml.etree.ElementTree` to find checkbox information in XML.

Reference: https://hypotenuselabs.medium.com/attack-on-checkbox-when-data-ingestion-gets-ugly-999fcdc5e000